# Error when I interpolate an array into an element polymer from Angular 2

Tags: angular, polymer

I have a problem between Polymer and Angular 2 when I want to work with Array type.

In Polymer all works properly, I define the template where I use an Array type to shown several images

```
<template>    
 <button class="heading" aria-controls="collapse1" on-click="toggle">
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[images]]">
     <template is="dom-repeat" items=[[images]]>
        <img src="[[item]]" width="[[imageWidth]]" height="[[imageHeight]]"/>
     </template>
  </template>
  <span>[[title]]</span>
 </button>
<template>
```

In the script section I define the properties:

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  properties: {
    images: {
      type: Array
    },
    imageWidth: {
      type: String,
      value: "20"
    },
    imageHeight: {
      type: String,
      value: "20"
    },
    title: {
      type: String
      value: "Default title"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

When I use this in a Polymer app, all works.

```
<my-element title="Itinerary" images='["icon.png","icon2.png","icon3.png","icon4.png"]' imageWidth="100px" imageHeight="100px"></my-element>
```

The problem is when I use it in Angular 2 app and I try to interpolate an array.

```
<my-element title="Itinerary" images='{{images}}' imageWidth="100px" imageHeight="100px"></my-element>
```

In ngOnInit method I set the value of images:

```
images: string[]
ngOnInit() {
 this.images = ['icon1.svg', 'icon2.svg']
}
```

But Chrome throws the next error:

```
polymer-micro.html:277 [dom-repeat::dom-repeat]: 
expected array for `items`, found icon1.svg,icon2.svg
```

I try several modifications in this code but I do not found the good one. Please, anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With curly braces you get a string interpolation, and looking at the error message, that's not what you want.

To actually pass objects, you have to bind with brackets like so:

```
<my-element ... [images]='images' ...></my-element>
```